# Would a comma go in the phrase, "That's it[,] just lie there"?

Tags: commas

I was watching a movie, and the subtitle said, "*Yeah, that's it, just lie there*." I know that movie subtitles can always be incredibly inaccurate, but I was wondering if it's correct to add a comma before "*just lie there*." Would that be a comma splice, or is it correct the way it is?

Answer (score 1):

> "Yeah, that's it, just lie there."

The actual *purpose* of the comma is to indicate where you would insert pauses if the sentence was spoken.  Since this sounds natural as spoken dialogue, it's fine.

As a counter example, consider this:

> Yeah, that's, it just lie there.

With the comma in a different place, you now have "it" paired with "lie", which totally changes the meaning (and is ungrammatical), and leaves a hanging "that's" which isn't paired with anything.  *However*, you never know -- this could be a meaningful line of dialogue in some strange context.